# Failed to open Crystal Reports

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

When I try to run crystal reports the following Error is appears:

> Transaction (Process ID 159) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction

Note: Report is connect directly to stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds to me like it's a SQL Server issue and not Crystal. The query that you are executing is causing a deadlock situation. Try running SQL Profiler while executing your report and see what's causing the deadlock.